# How to implicitly deduce the type information of the element in array in function templates

Tags: c++

Been trying working on function `inner_product`, my solutions is:

```
    template <typename E, typename T>
    E inner_product(T &a, T &b) {
        int length = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
        E sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            sum += a[i] * b[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

still, I have to explicitly declare the type argument when invoking this function

```
    int a[2] = {1, 1};
    int b[2] = {2, 2};
    inner_product<int>(a, b); // print out 4
```

I want to know is there any way to **implicitly deduce the type of the element of the array**? Besides the solution where adding a extra argument for compiler to deduce the type, i.e: `E inner_product(T &a, T &b, E init)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can add some extra args, this way array size is also getting deduced:

```
template <typename T, ::std::size_t items_count>
T inner_product(T ( & a )[items_count], T ( & b )[items_count]) {
    T sum{};
    for (::std::size_t i{}; i < items_count; ++i) {
        sum += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Why should it be `::std::size_t` here instead of `std::size_t`?

Comment: thank you for your answer, however I'm not deducing the array size, but the type of the element of the array.

Comment: @lubgr To refer to `size_t` from `std` namespace from *global* namespace.

Comment: @YuXiao You are calculating array size anyway, with this approach `int length = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);` can be omitted.

Comment: But this is not particularly tied to the deduction of this template, right? So, this is the same as defining a local variable as `::std::size_t n = 42`.

Comment: @lubgr Yes. I tend to use `::` for all the function / type / variable names from global namespace in all circumstances to be on the safe side.

Comment: the usage of `T sum{}` is to initialize the `sum` to 0?

Comment: @YuXiao Yes, or to initialize it with default constructor (if it is a class). See [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) with [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference).

```
template <typename T>
auto inner_product(T &a, T &b) -> typename std::remove_reference<decltype(a[0])>::type {
    int length = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    typename std::remove_reference<decltype(a[0])>::type sum = 0;
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sum += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Or since C++14 you can just

```
template <typename T>
auto inner_product(T &a, T &b) {
    int length = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    std::remove_reference_t<decltype(a[0])> sum = 0;
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sum += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```